# What plant is it?

Tags: botany, species-identification

Do you know what plant is it? I found it in France
[image]

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: @MarchHo possibly because there is no mention of size/scale, what the overall plant looks like, where/when it was found (mountain, valley, seaside, plains, dry, wet, hot, cold, summer, winter, etc.).

Comment: That looks like a magnolia tree, those pods should bloom into an impressive white flower. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnolia. While I can tell as much as that, I'm not familiar with identifying these any further.

Comment: I dont think it is a Magnolia tree because of the its size its huge!!!

Answer (score 9):

That's a magnolia tree. They are grown around the world for ornament, wood, and foliage.

The seedpods are a bit further along than my nice, unripe one, but as they ripen and dry, all those "scales" (see the line up the middle of each one?) open up and let a ripe seed into the world.

[image]  [image]

Note the shiny, thick (evergreen) pointed oblong leaves with brown fuzzy undersides.

[image]

I would guess by the seedpod and the shape of the leaves that it's a [Magnolia *grandiflora*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnolia_grandiflora). Magnolias are an [ancient tree](http://eol.org/pages/44478/overview), like the Ginko.

> Magnolia is one of the most ancient angiosperm (flowering plant) genera, with fossil specimens dated at 20 million years old, and fossils of plants belonging to the Magnoliaceae family dating to 95 million years ago. The genus appears to have evolved before bees appeared, so the floral structure developed to encourage pollination by beetles...
>
> Eight species of Magnolia are native to the southeastern U.S., where they have become a popular symbol of southern culture, used in myriad place names and in literature, music (including magnolia-titled songs by the Grateful Dead, Beck, and JJ Cale), movies, and art. Magnolia is the state tree of Mississippi, and M. grandiflora (southern magnolia or sweet bay) is the state flower of both Mississippi and Louisiana.